# Swift, Core Data, Optional Integer16 and keyPath

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity in CoreData which has an optional property of type Integer 16.  It can genuinely be nil and in my application I want to refer to it as an Int? type.  As Int? (or for that matter Int16?) isn't a recognised Objective-C type, the compiler throws a bit of a wobbly. I want to avoid using code like NSNumber?.intValue throughout so I've actually set up my ManagedObject type with custom accessors for this property.  My question relates to identifying the property through #keyPath rather than a static string.  In Core Data the field is named 'pin' on entity 'User'.  Here's the code I have:

```
class User: NSManagedObject {
// MARK: - Properties
static let pinKey = "pin"

@NSManaged internal(set) var name: String
@NSManaged fileprivate var primitivePin: NSNumber?

internal(set) var pin: Int? {
    get {
        willAccessValue(forKey: #keyPath(pin))  // THIS LINE ERRORS
        let value: Int? = primitivePin.map { $0.intValue }
        didAccessValue(forKey: User.pinKey)
        return value
    }
    set {
        willChangeValue(forKey: User.pinKey)
        primitivePin = newValue.map { NSNumber(value: Int16($0)) }
        didChangeValue(forKey: User.pinKey)
    }
}
```

}

The line in error is what I 'want' to achieve but of course the var pin isn't an obj-c type and the compiler complains, so I have defined the static constant pinKey as you can see.  #keyPath feels like the right way to go about it, and the entity does have a field called pin, but in this scenario is the only option open to me to use a static value?

Answer (score 2):

In `#keyPath` you have to specify property name. If you don't have defined property called `pin`, you will receive an error. In your case you have to use `#keyPath(User.primitivePin)`. I believe this should work.

Also, i guess, calling map is redundant here. You can write directly `let value = primitivePin?.intValue` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but what has me confused is, to take the 'name' property as an example, Core Data in the background creates a property called primitiveName for this @managed property.  I would still reference name as #keyPath(name) and not #keyPath(primitiveName).  If I used #keyPath(primitivePin) would Core Data map that to the entity pin property in the same way (the property on the entity in the Data Model is pin, not primitivePin)?  There's something about this that isn't clicking and I can't find any decent information relating to this scenario.

Comment: PS: You're right about the accessor of course, I was getting carried away!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is....with custom properties/accessors #keyPath can't used as there is no defined @NSManaged property for it - as Maksym points out.  However, you can't use the defined primitive for it either, instead using the property name as a String as also shown in the code above (User.pinKey)